# how to send soap 1.2 request to webserver using php

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I want to send this request to webserver  this is my wsdl `http://41.206.29.43:8080/BridgeService/WalletMultiBankServices?wsdl`

```html
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:web="http://webservice.multibank.com">
<soap:Header/><soap:Body>
<web:postNESingleRequest><web:neSingleRequest><![CDATA[<NESingleRequest>
<SessionID>40130513080114014100872937033</SessionID>
<DestinationCode>999</DestinationCode>
<ChannelCode>3</ChannelCode>
<AccountIdentificationNumber>9998887771</AccountIdentificationNumber>
</NESingleRequest>]]>
</web:neSingleRequest></web:postNESingleRequest>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I recommend you reading http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: Need the full WSDL URL to give good help -- don't put servername in there, there are important details in the WSDL file.

Comment: ok this is my wsdl  http://41.206.29.43:8080/BridgeService/WalletMultiBankServices?wsdl